# How can I pass DataReader/DataTable to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC and trying to write a simple MVC 3 application which reads customer data inside a class in model and return it to view using controller. Reader shows it has rows but when load to table and pass to view as model, it is null. I need a simple solution to pass either a `DataTable` to view or `DataReader` to view where I can convert to `DataTable`.

Here is the code:

```
namespace MvcApplication3.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public DataTable GetCustomers(OdbcDataReader rds)
        {
            String ConString = "DSN=Northwind;Uid=;Pwd=;";
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS";
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

            using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConString))
            {
                con.Open();
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(SQL, con);
                rds = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }

    }
}

namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Default1/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Customer cs = new Customer();
            OdbcDataReader rd = new OdbcDataReader();
            cs.GetCustomers(rd);

            DataTable tb = new DataTable();
            tb.Load(rd);
            return View(tb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not pass `DataReader` or `DataTable` to a view. Do not pass `DataReader` or `DataTable` to a ViewModel either. Create a POCO that represents the data you need to work with - this is called a Model, Pass that to a class that knows how to massage that data into something presentable - this is called a ViewModel, then pass that into your View. To make your life easier try out [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).

Comment: I was really trying to avoid EF and use my own DAL type classes. I am passing a datatable and its working on view. But I will modify to your suggestion to a class and then see if its less code required.  Thanks for tip

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Displaying-DataTables-in-Asp-Net-MVC-Razor-Page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A view in mvc is always associated with a strongly typed model I.e a class..so in your case..just create a class with a list..while fetching data insert that data into a list and pass that class into the view..

```
class A {
    public string name{get;set;}
    public int age{get;set;}
}

//code when fetching data
//this list should be in the class where you fetch the data
Public list<A> list=new list<A>();
while(datareader.read)
{
    A Aobj=new A();
    String name=reader['name'].tostring();
    int age =Convert.ToInt(reader['age']);
    A.name=name;
    A.age=age;
    list.add(A);
}//end of while loop

//action resut
public ViewResult yourview(){
    Return View(list);
}

//now you can access the data from the view.              
By....
@model IEnumerable<A>
//here A is your class name
@foreach(var data in Model){
    <div>@data.age</div>
}
```

Sorry for the code format... posted from mobile

Comment: Is it the code?..cuz I just posted the code while travelling in a bus from my mobile

Comment: No its OK for me, its good to get an idea how to do it. Thanks for posting it its nice and helpful.

Comment: @suryaDeepak I'll remove the -1 once the formatting is fixed.

Comment: Since my computer has gone broke..can u format it for me plz..:)

Comment: In MVC a model is not always associated with a strongly typed class. A strongly typed class is a luxury you do not always get or have.

Comment: The guy did this from a mobile device. Don't be a douche

Answer (score 8):

for the  controller  :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DataTable dt = GetData();

            return View(dt);
        }
```

Then in the view :

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data;
```

..................
..............
........

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                                {
                                    <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                                }
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                                    {
                                        <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: If I wanted to send this datatable from this view back into the controller to be used by another view how would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Do not pass a `DataReader` into a view - convert it to a disconnected object/model first.

If you are using Razor, add this to the top of your .cshtml page to tell it what type of model to expect:

```
@model  System.Data.DataTable
```

Comment: Umm, this will work, sure, but its still ugly and bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

1.Pass datatable into the view.

```
 public ActionResult my()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table",con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return View(dt);

    }
```

2.Accept the datatable in the view

```
@model System.Data.DataTable


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>my</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div> 
       No of rows= @Model.Rows.Count
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try it out :) (y)

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this in your view and one thing what you want display expected details like based on Index;

```
@using System.Data;
@model DataTable

<h2>Report</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>

                <th>@Model.ColumnName[1]</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>

                    <td>@row[1]</td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```